# sh script to capture text and add to space separated variable

Tags: bash

I have a conf file that contains 1 to n number of lines that are formated like this:

`server $hostname $something_else`

I want to be able to take all hostname variables and insert them into a space separated string. I think I should do something like:

`awk '/^server/ {print $2}' file.conf`

But instead of printing lines, how would I get a variable with "hostname1 hostname2 ... hostname n"?

Comment: Why do you want them in a space separated string? They're already whitespace separated. If you want to iterate over them, this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your current output, paste it one after the other, and assign the result to a var:

```
V=$(awk '/^server/ {print $2}' file.conf | paste -s -d' ')
```

This could also be done with awk alone, using printf to avoid the automatic new line of print:

```
V=$(awk '/^server/ {printf("%s ", $2)}' file.conf)
```